# The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**i want to assign  value of defulttitle  into the text but its showing some error..**

```
 final foldertitle =
 TextEditingController(text: folderbox.isEmpty ? defulttitle : folderbox.get(1));
```

```
class Addnotes extends StatefulWidget {
  const Addnotes(
      {super.key,
     
      
      this.defulttitle = "My passwords.."});

 
  final String defulttitle;
 
  @override
  State<Addnotes> createState() => _AddnotesState();
}

class _AddnotesState extends State<Addnotes> {
 
  BuildContext? myContext;
 
  final foldertitle =
      TextEditingController(text: folderbox.isEmpty ? defulttitle : folderbox.get(1)); //here i cant assign the value of defulttitle into the text..can anyone explain?thank you..
```

why i cant assign the value of defulttitle into the text..can anyone explain?thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lazy initialization with `late`.

```dart
BuildContext? myContext;
 
late final foldertitle =....;
```

Also you can use initState. but you may need to create variable for BuildContext, better will be passing using method.

Comment: I appreciate it..if you dont feel bad can you explain because of why this error was came?

Comment: It was added on null-safety,you can check analysis_options default rules, and [lazy-initialization ](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#lazy-initialization)